# QML Image: Cannot open: qrc:/untitled3/profilna.png

Tags: qml, qtquick2, qt6

I'm dealing with this simple yet frustrating problem for a long time in Qt6.

> I create a new Qt Quick project and set my Android Qt Clang x86_64 kit (cmake). The issue starts when I want to add an image in my application. I add the image into the projects folder and use the code
> `Image{ source = "profilna.png" }`
> , but when I built it, I got a warning saying : "libappuntitled3_x86_64.so: qrc:/untitled3/Main.qml:10:5: QML Image: Cannot open: qrc:/untitled3/profilna.png" in the Application Output.
> I'm a complete beginner in Qt Quick and don't understand why it works in Desktop MinGW kit and not on Android. After that I added resource.qrc (prefix name "/img") and added the image (that is in a folder "img") there, but it still doesn't work. I have also added
> `set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)`
> , didn't work.

main.qml

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Image{
        x: 62
        y: 39
        width: 153
        height: 345
        source:"qrc:/img/img/profilna.png"
    }
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(untitled3 VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

find_package(Qt6 6.4 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Quick)

qt_standard_project_setup()

qt_add_executable(appuntitled3
    main.cpp
)

qt_add_qml_module(appuntitled3
    URI untitled3
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES Main.qml
)

set_target_properties(appuntitled3 PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER my.example.com
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

target_link_libraries(appuntitled3
    PRIVATE Qt6::Quick
)

install(TARGETS appuntitled3
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)
```

resource.qrc

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/img">
        <file>img/profilna.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anywhere in your cmake file where you include your resource.qrc file. But you shouldn't even need to manually create that file anymore in Qt6. In your cmake file, add your images this way:

```
qt_add_resources(appuntitled3 "assets"
    PREFIX "/img"
    FILES "img/profilna.png"
)
```

Your qml should then be able to access "qrc:/img/img/profilna.png".